# How to find out which version of API is available for a certain OSX version?

Tags: swift, macos, macos-mojave

I want to retrieve some meta data of a photo asset in the Photo library. Basically the name, type and location of it. I want to implement it as a command line utility in Swift.

Here is the code I have come up with

```
var allPhotos : PHFetchResult<PHAsset>? = nil
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
```

But it fails to compile because of `'fetchAssets(with:options:)' is only available in macOS 10.15 or newer`.

My app is targeted to run on 10.14 and my MBP is still running 10.14.

When I check the documentation page (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phasset),

I can't find the os version information next to each API on the page.

[image]

What is the easiest way to find such information?

Also how can I make the code work for 10.14?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## macOS Version Requirements

> What is the easiest way to find such information?

It says on [the page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phasset/1624725-fetchassets) that 10.15+ is required:

---

[image]

## Alternatives

> Also how can I make the code work for 10.14?

Use [fetchAssets(in:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phasset/1624757-fetchassets) (min 10.13) instead of [fetchAssets(with:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phasset/1624725-fetchassets) (min 10.15).

Comment: As a suggestion, I would download Kapeli's Dash and install the iOS documentation. I find it to be much easier to navigate than wading through web pages. Additionally, it's available offline.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks for the suggestion! Indeed if i have to dive into each method's webpage to find its support version it seems to be rather time-consuming.